# What is cast and convert in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sql, sql-studio

What is cast and convert in SFMC

eg- SELECT
Count(*) as Count,
CAST(GETUTCDATE() as date) AS Day,
GETUTCDATE() AS [Updated Date]
FROM ENT.[Demo4 Contact__IQ]
WHERE [Status Code] = 'Active'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAST & CONVERT are SQL conversion functions in SFMC. Both can be used to convert an input expression into specific data type, but CONVERT additionally provides formatting capability. Syntax is as follows:

> CAST ( expression AS data_type [ ( length ) ] )
> CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )

The valid input values for *style* can be found in the official SQL reference mentioned at the end of this answer.

> Salesforce Marketing Cloud user MS SQL server database and its syntax is T-SQL (refer [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwBzkHQMjr4)).

> SQL support for the SQL Query Activity is based on, but doesn’t
> precisely correspond to, SQL Server 2016 capabilities. (refer
> [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_sql_reference.htm&type=5))

For detailed information on CAST & CONVERT, check [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) out. Note that not all of the information given in the reference link might hold true with reference to Mktg Cloud, but most of it should.